# How to set the width of a Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Table table = new Table ();        
TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
TableRow row2 = new TableRow();
TableCell cell1_1 = new TableCell { RowSpan = 2,  };           
TableCell cell1_2 = new TableCell
{
    Text = string.Format("<h4>{0}</h4><br />{1}<br/>",
        product.ProductName, "Product No:" + product.Id),
    HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left,
};
TableCell cell1_3 = new TableCell { Text = "Unit Price<hr/>"};  
TableCell cell1_4 = new TableCell { Text = "Quantity<hr/>" };            
TableCell cell1_5 = new TableCell { Text = "Product Total<hr/>"};
TableCell cell1_6 = new TableCell();
TableCell cell2_1 = new TableCell();
TableCell cell2_2 = new TableCell { Text = "Rs " + product.Price};
TableCell cell2_3 = new TableCell();            
TableCell cell2_4 = new TableCell { Text = "Rs " + (order.Quantity * product.Price) };
TableCell cell2_5 = new TableCell();
```

How can i set the width of this table? When i am trying table.Witdh its not working

Comment: I don't see the code where you're trying to set `table.witdh`. What happens if you try it?

Comment: when i m trying table.width its showing the same result. this code results a table that goes out of screen horizontally

Comment: So add the code where you assign a `Width` to the table and where you add it to the page. Show also the aspx with the container-control where you add the table programmatically(if it's not the page itself) including all related style sheets. It would also help to understand the issue if you'd show a screenshot and what html is rendered.

Comment: how can i show the screenshot here?

Comment: You can include images with enough reputation. Until then include a link and i'll edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Table table = new Table();
table.Width=new Unit("100%");
```

or

```
 table.Width = new Unit("70px");
```

Where `Unit` belongs to [`System.Web.UI.WebControls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Give `   table.BorderWidth = 1; ` to see the edges of the table, check the container width too

Comment: edges of the table goes out of the screen

Comment: That means the code i supplied works fine. so adjust the `%` or `px` value as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

table.Width = new Unit("25%")

Works for me.